# Is there a system that only contains electric dipole moment but not higher electric multipole moments?

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion, moment

Does there exist such thing, if it does, which charge distribution could generate it?
If it doesn't exist, can it be proven?

Comment: Perhaps the molecule made from an electron-positron pair (positronium) as it's strictly two charges of opposite charge that are bound together (though very short lived).

Comment: In the center of mass coordinate,what about its octupole moment?

Comment: Not sure, there might be more people who can actually answer this question though.

Comment: well,thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Mind not a very helpful answer, I admit, but in 1 dimension, charge density = const * x, going from x = -infinity to x = +infinity has an infinite dipole moment and no higher orthogonal moments